# Can't send ETC using Ledger with MyEtherWallet

Tags: ethereum-classic, myetherwallet, ledger-nano-s

I have an address that has both ETH and ETC. They are in Ledger Nano S. I transferred ETH to the address and it works fine. Then I transferred ETC to the same address. Now I tried to use MyEtherWallet to transfer ETC and it gives an error "invalid network id". I didn't use the ETC in the Chrome App earlier and didn't realize there was a different address (legacy). How do I get my ETC from there to my legacy address in the ETC chain?

Comment: Solved my problem. https://ledger.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/i-sent-etc-on-an-eth-address-how-can-i-recover-them

Comment: Hi there. Could you add an answer that summarise the steps you followed from that link?